# What do you call flags which can only be set?

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns, math

Is there a correct name for this idempotent primitive?

```
public class Flag
{
    public bool IsSet { get; private set; }

    public void Set()
    {
        IsSet = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This flag can also be read also...I think the term you are referring to is asymmetric accessor accessibility.

Comment: This looks like C#, do you want the answer in Java?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not sure it matters for this example.

Comment: I added an example of what you would typically do in Java anyway.

Comment: How about an `onSwitch` - i.e. you can only switch it `on`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Thanks for understanding the question

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield - Frustrating sometimes isn't it :) I think people are confused with the word `idempotent`. Perhaps you could remove that and change your code so that there is a **public** `set` that sets it `true` and a `get` that returns it.

Comment: This class _is_ idempotent but that's not the defining factor. Add a `Reset()` and it's entirely different but still idempotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in e.e. this is a Set Latch as opposed to a Set-Reset (SR) Latch.

Would a fuse would be a persistent version that requires manual replacement of its database to reset?

Comment: I believe a fuse is a very close match, in that if I require a new 'on' flag, I would have to create a new one (i.e. replace the fuse).

Comment: I think perhaps an analogy between analogue electronics and software is pushing it.. A real fuse breaks (returns null? gets destroyed?) when a the input current is exceeded for enough time. Not sure how you could pass an overcurrent bool without e.g. casting 3 to it :)

Answer (score 3):

How about **tripSwitch** or perhaps **onSwitch**?

**Added**

A **[latch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latching_switch)** might nearly be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you - good suggestions. I would love to know if there's a definite 'right answer' on this though, like how we have names for 'semaphores', etc.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - If you only read the first sentence it works for me `A latching switch is a switch that maintains its state after being activated`. I disagree with the rest of it anyway.

Comment: Yes, my complaint is about that make/break example too, at least in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Flags that can only be set from within the class would be **readonly** ones from outside.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in Java if you assume only method will be used is

```
class Component {
    private volatile boolean closed = false;

    public boolean isClosed() { return closed; }

    public void close() { closed = true; }
}
```

The field is volatile as `running` or `closed` flags are often set by a different thread to the one it is used in.

Note: even if you make  a field `final` you can still change the value using reflection as it can by-pass the security model (Assuming your SecurityManager allows it, which it does by default)

Comment: Thanks for the answer on writing concurrent code in Java which avoids thread caching issues (it's the same in C# btw). However, the question is more primitive than this, and applies to all OO languages which support mutable state. I'm simply looking for the name of the design pattern, if you will - I'm sure people with backgrounds in electronics must know the answer ;)

Comment: In electronics it's called a fuse.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thinking about this some more, I'd be happy to accept this as the answer if you posted it as one. The analogy is spot-on: returning to the initial state once you've 'broken' the fuse requires it to be replaced - the fuse cannot be unbroken.

Comment: The analogy works but you wouldn't want to call this a fuse. I think @PeterWishart has the proper naming.